# Boundary of a set is subset of the set if and only if the set is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$. I wish to show that

> $\partial A \subset A$ if and only if $A$ is closed.

I am not seeking a full answer, but just some sort of hint of how to approach this. It is the "$\Longrightarrow$" direction I'm stuck on.

"$\Longrightarrow$" Suppose $\partial A \subset A$. I wish to show $\bar{A} = A$ (the closure of $A$ is equal to $A$), but I'm not sure how to show this. I thought of "element chasing" for this, but this doesn't seem like it will work.

"$\Longleftarrow$" Suppose $A$ is closed. Then $A = \bar{A}$, and we have $\partial A = \bar{A} \setminus \mathring{A} \subset \bar{A} = A$, done.

Comment: Give a definition of boundary; depending on the definition, this problem is more or less difficult.

Comment: @KeeferRowan $\partial A = \bar{A} \setminus \mathring{A}$. I've also proven that $\partial A$ is closed, $\partial A = \bar{A} \cap \overline{X \setminus A}$, $\partial A \cap \mathring{A} = \varnothing$, and $\partial A \cup \mathring{A} = \bar{A}$.

Comment: @KeeferRowan: You can infer the OP’s definition from the proof the right to left implication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\partial A \subseteq A$. Using your definition, $\partial A = \overline{A} \setminus \text{Int}(A)$. Then, we have that $\overline{A} = \partial A \cup \text{Int}(A)$. Thus, if $x \in \overline{A}$, then $x \in \partial A$ or $x \in \text{Int}(A)$. In the first case, $x \in \partial A \subseteq A$. In the latter case, then $x \in \text{Int}(A) \subseteq A$. Thus, we have that $\overline{A} \subseteq A$ so $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You know that $\operatorname{bdry}A=(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus\operatorname{int}A$. If $A$ is not closed, there is some $x\in(\operatorname{cl}A)\setminus A$; is $x\in\operatorname{bdry}A$? Is $x\in A$?